# Regex, close it off in both ends?

Tags: regex

So i made this regex: `[0-3][0-9][0-1][0-9]\d{2}-\d{4}?[^0-9]`

But when i use this regex it will find numbers as 100880-1098.

But it will also find numbers as 661651100880-1098.

Is there a way to close it off in both ends so it dosent fin the numbers before or after the "100880-1098" ?

I have tried `^[0-3][0-9][0-1][0-9]\d{2}-\d{4}?[^0-9]$`

but it dosent work

Comment: I suggest to put a [word-boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) at the start and the end of the regex. A word-boundary `\b` matches the transition between a word-character and a non-wordcharacter.

Comment: So if i got the code "\b[0-3][0-9][0-1][0-9]\d{2}-\d{4}?[^0-9]". then it will still find this "111111-1111a" How do i get it to only take the numbers and not let the last letter be a hit aswell?

Comment: The regex `\bX\b` will match 'X' in the string "a X b" and also "X", but not in the string "aXb" or "aX b" or "a Xb". While the regex `^X$` will only match the string "X". I'm assuming that you're tring to match your numbers as part of the string, not as a whole string. Both numbers and letters are word-characters.

Comment: But if i make "^[0-3][0-9][0-1][0-9]\d{2}-\d{4}?[^0-9]$" i get no hits. 

If i do "\b[0-3][0-9][0-1][0-9]\d{2}-\d{4}?[^0-9]\b" i still get a letter after my numbers

Comment: I just noticed that you have a `[^0-9]` as the end. Because of the class-negation `^`, that matches anything BUT a digit. So that part would match also a letter. So does your regex really need that part?

Comment: If i delete the [^0-9] part. i will get hits of "111111-1111111111-1111". so it will hit numbers after the numbers iwant

Comment: got it working now with \b[0-3][0-9][0-1][0-9]\d{2}-\d{4}\b . Thx for the answer

Comment: Good for you :) Btw, as an alternative to using word-boundaries. There are also [Look-arounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Although javascript regex only knows the look-aheads.  It's a way to check for something, without actually taking it into the match result. F.e. `[0-9](?=[^0-9])` or `[0-9](?![0-9])`